# MongoDB: return objects that have intersection on arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, intersection

This is a question about shaping a MongoDB query...

Suppose I have many objects. They have a property called `some_array` and the values can be:

```
object1 = {
    "some_array": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}

object2 = {
    "some_array": [2, 4, 5]
}

object3 = {
    "some_array": [4, 7, 9]
}
```

What I want to do: given another array [2, 7], I want to find all objects, that contain either 2 or 7. So all three objects can be found, because `object1` and `object2` have `2`, and `object3` has `7`.

This means, if the given array has an intersection with the array in the object, then return that object.

Anyone has a suggestion for the query?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array

Answer (score 0):

you can using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array) because

> the $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field
> equals any value in the specified array. To specify an $in expression

:

```
find( { some_array: { $in: [ 2, 7 ] } } )
```